# How to keep few things intact in javascript replace function

Tags: javascript, regex, json, replace

I have a JSON string with many segments as shown below:

```
"@rid":{"cluster":13,"position":0}
```

I want all these to be replaced with

```
"@rid":"#13:0"
```

'13' and '0' are just taken as example, there can be any number in place of them and all such segments in JSON can have different numbers, so if we generalize, the problem is to replace

```
"@rid":{"cluster":<<X>>,"position":<<Y>>}
```

with

```
"@rid":"<<X>>:<<Y>>"
```

Note X and Y should remain intact after replacement.

Comment: Shouldn't you try something first before you ask a simple question?

Comment: is this there are only two segments in your json file?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=[^{]*})"[^"]*"|,
```

You can try this.Replace by ``.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/6

Next you can replace `{}` by `"` to get your exact result.